# Help identify this frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I'm not sure what brand this is at all. Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried looking up the serial but i am unsure what the last serial number is. It appears to be a "b" or "6" but I am unsure. The serial is located on the bottom bracket and it appears to have been originally green, but was then painted over as grey.

[image: bike frame]

[image: serial number]

Comment: The last digit of the serial # looks more like a 5 to me

Comment: Pretty darn generic.  Lugged frame and downtube shifters place it prior to 1985 or so, I'm thinking.  Cottered crank makes it earlier still -- 1975, perhaps.  Large flange front hub (which was common for the era).  Can't make out the brakes but probably generic calipers.  Very likely 27" wheels.

Comment: More pictures would help. A clear close-up of the different parts of the drive-train (front and rear gears, front and rear derailers), of the brakes, of the brake levers, of the shifters, and of the stem. If there's any kind of markings visible on them, also the front of the head tube and the hubs of the wheels.